# How to set Jquery dropdown checklist?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(

function(){

   //is this right syntax for jquery dropdown plugin??
   $j('#data .xyz').dropdownchecklist(); 
   }
 }
);
</script>

<div id="data">
 <table class="xyz">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Name:<br /> <%=select_tag 'Names', options_from_collection_for_select(@available_names, 'id', 'name', selected = params[:Names].to_i) %> 
   </td>
  </tr>
 <tbody>
<table/>
```

Is it the right way for using jquery dropdown checklist?? here is the link for plugin

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Comment: You should provide a link to the plugin you are using so that others can have a look at it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you at least mention that you're using a jQuery plugin and link to it.

Comment: Sorry about that here is the link http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#data .xyz` should refer to a `<select>` element with `<option>`'s to turn into a dropdown check list.
What your jQuery selector is doing, is pick up the `<table>` element with the class `.xyz`.

You should change your selector into:
`$j('#data .xyz select').dropdownchecklist();`

Comment: @user659068: I can also notice you have one extra `}` in your code.
In general, look at the errors the browser generates to see if there's anything wrong. If it still doesn't work, please provide a link to your page or a http://jsfiddle.net/ to the example that isn't working.